# unable to read key from json using JsonPath

Tags: java, json

I am trying to read a json value by providing json key.
code that i am tried. document is alreadt load it has above json. 
i am using this link `https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath`

```
jsonPath = "$.Contact[?(@.key  =~ /ContactID/i)].value";
Object attrValue = JsonPath.read(document, jsonPath);
```

"attrValue is empty". please guide me on this. thanks in advance

```
{
  Date=/Date(1454410800000+1300)/,
  Type=ACCREC,
  Total=7000,
  Status=PAID,
  Contact={
    Name=Abc,
    Phones=[

    ],
    Addresses=[

    ],
    ContactID=df400dcd-6bdb-4cb5-98ce-496ec64c253f,
    ContactGroups=[

    ],
    ContactPersons=[

    ],
    HasValidationErrors=false
  },
  DueDate=/Date(1454756400000+1300)/,

  SubTotal=7000,
  TotalTax=0,
  AmountDue=0,
  HasErrors=false,
  InvoiceID=7aaa5fe5-25c3-47f9-b37f-f732b7705ee4


 }
```

Comment: solved the problem. my jsonPath was wrong